# How do I show a percentage as a Metric in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have data that has this format:

```
{
    "area": "cats",
    "healthy": true,
    "timestamp": "2016-02-12T14:00:00.601000",
}

{
    "area": "dogs",
    "healthy": false,
    "timestamp": "2016-02-12T15:00:00.601000",
}
```

As you can see, 'healthy' can be true or false. I want to show the percentage of all records where healthy:true as a Metric in Kibana. I've been trying for several days with no success. It feels like it should be incredibly easy, especially as the pie chart displays it when I hover over it.

[image]

Can you help?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You actually can't show percentage in Kibana. There is a feature request in Kibana  (https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2284).

But for now, you have two options:

- stick to pie chart, where you can view percentage
- implement a data table, where you can see the count of each value.

Comment: FYI I can grab the es data in python, calculate the % and then post that to a new index.

Comment: @MeinFarzer could you perhaps post an example?